# Verify if valid torrent file in Python?

Tags: python, bittorrent, torrent

Does someone know a way in Python to check, if a torrent file (i.e. file.torrent) is valid? 
`os.path.exists()` works well, if you want to know if the file exists in a given location, but I want to check if the existing file is a valid torrent in itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update 1:**

Since many of you find the description above to general, here is a more detailed one!
I download torrents with the `request` library and put them into the watch folder of the client, which then automatically starts the download.

```
def download_torrent(torrent_url, file_path, pause=None, verbose=True):
    """ 
    Downloads a torrent file, if it doesn't already exist.

    PARAMETERS
    - torrent_url:    torrent url
    - file_path:      absolute local filepath
    - pause:          integer number of seconds
    - verbose:        True/False
    """
    import requests

    if not os.path.exists(file_path): # torrent file does not exist in location
        r = requests.get(torrent_url)
        filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as torrent:
            if verbose: print "> Downloading '%s'..." %(os.path.basename(file_path))
            torrent.write(r.content)
        if pause != None: 
            sleep(pause)
    else: # torrent file exists already
        if verbose: 
            print "! '%s' already exists, skipping file..." %(os.path.basename(file_path))
```

This works fine in most case. However the client fails to load some torrent files, since they are corrupted.
I'm looking for a way to identify those files and thus preventing them from being loaded by the client.

Comment: How would you define a *valid torrent file?*

Comment: I guess you could use `try ... except` with [this](https://github.com/7sDream/torrent_parser) library's parse function.

Comment: The question is too broad, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: compare the `.torrent` file to its MD5 checksum [superuser - How to validate Torrent-Files?](https://superuser.com/a/263132)

Comment: Thanks @davedwards, my problem seems to stem from non compatibility of torrent clients, such as Transmission, with non-english characters inside torrents.

Comment: @davedwards CreeDorofl mentioned in the thread, referred by you that hash checking is already part of the Bittorrent protocol, so I guess it would be redundant to check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify that a torrent file is valid you need bencoder/decoder implementation to parse the file and then check whether the mandatory fields from [BEP3](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) are present and in the expected form.

[libtorrent](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent) provides python bindings. Bittornado should contain a pure python implementation, although it is a bit dated.